# Getting acurate time-derived bytes per second counter from Windows perfmon counters

Tags: windows, perfmon

On Linux, I'm used to having `/proc/diskstats`, which has counters with the total number of bytes read/written. You can mathematically derive those over time (in Influx DB, rrdtool, etc) to obtain an accurate throughput rate. Is there no such thing on Windows?

For instance, this [Nagios](https://outsideit.net/monitoring-windows-disk-load/) plugin uses `DiskWriteBytesPerSec` and `DiskReadBytesPerSec`. (partial) documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394308(v=vs.85).aspx). But these seem useless, because they only seem to measure the last second. So, if you have monitoring that polls per minute, this is useless.

I tried looking here under physical disk:

[image: Screenshot of windows perfmon]

But I can't find a counter for bytes read or written. Is there really no such thing?